# planes from images not correct

Tags: modeling, texturing, 3d-view

I have been following a tutorial and they put a image from plane image on the side of the scene to add shadow from off camera, it says you have to click the diffuse plus transparency. I don't have that option anywhere. What can I do?

Comment: are you using cycles?

Comment: yes, I have umped between that and blender render and nothing happens. I am also using version 2.79

Comment: Anyone? Bump...